# WiFi networks RSSI level extraction in Python/Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, wifi

The problem I'm trying to tackle is extracting the RSSI levels of all the wifi networks discoverable by my laptop.
My requirements are to be able to view RSSI of all wifi networks, and to be able to poll new data every second or so, since I'm trying to track the wifi RSSI for a computer moving around in a space.

So far I've heard of and tested two solutions, initiating the following commands with `subprocess` and parsing their output:

1. `cat /proc/net/wireless`, which outputs information for the current network only, and there doesn't seem to be a way to output information for all networks with this file obviously. It updates with a good-enough interval for me, but again, not all networks.
2. `iwlist scan`, which outputs information for the current network only, unless used with `sudo`, but since I want this automated in a program that will run the `iwlist sccan` command from within, sudo is a problem. Also, it seems to update the RSSI levels very slowly compared to the previous option, which is a no-go, since I need the RSSI levels updated by the second.

I would love to hear about any other solution to get this data. I'll note that I'm building the program in python, so any library would be good, or just a cli tool that I will invoke from within the python program.

Currently working with an Ubuntu 16.04 setup.

Thanks!

Comment: Understand that there is no standard for RSSI, and each vendor does it differently, even between different models from the same vendor. You cannot compare RSSI between vendors, and sometimes you cannot compare RSSI between different device models from the same vendor.

Comment: That is fine by me, I just need to see the patterns in the signal, so even if every hotspot I'm tracking has different RSSI lower and upper bound, all I need to track is the pattern of strengthening/weakening.

Answer (score 1):

On the command line you can use following command : 
`iwconfig` and look for `"Link Quality"` and `"Signal level"` values.

Or Use this command which updates the output of iwconfig every second:

```
watch -n1 iwconfig
```

Comment: It seems to give about the same info as /proc/net/wireless, I'd take a risk and say that is where it gets its information from, which doesn't help me get data about networks discoverable by my computer,but that my computer is not connected to

Comment: voted for the watch command. `watch -n1 -d cat /proc/net/wireless` works well for monitoring wifi signal.